# Access session variable from MVC razor view gives variable type instead of value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I am trying to access a session variable inside a MVC razor view, the session variable is of type  User which has a property UserID, the code is like the following:

```
<h3>@((User)Session["LoggedOnUser"]).UserID</h3>
```

It only prints the fully qualified type of the property instead of its value. I also tried the following:

```
@{User loginUser = (User)Session["LoggedOnUser"];}
<h3>@loginUser.UserID</h3>
```

It works this time. Can anyone tell me what's the difference of these two and why the first one does not work?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share how you applied session on the specific User domain? do i simply add session declaration in the User controller and that is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of where you placed your close bracket for the `Response.Write` (@) code block. You are calling Response.Write on the User object and not the UserID property. I believe calling Response.Write on the user ojbect will just use the ToString() method and return the fully qualified type name.

The following would have worked:

```
@((User)Session["LoggedOnUser"].UserID)
```

Notice the close bracket is after the property, not after the return value from the session dictionary.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed it as following and it works: @(((User)Session["LoggedOnUser"]).UserID)